# Moving contents of faulty drive into another drive

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10

The D: drive has been acting up lately on my Windows 10 computer. I plan on getting rid of the drive and buying a new one soon, but in the meantime I wanted to trasnfer all of the contents in this drive into the E: drive. I have lots of enviornment variables etc. tied into the existing faualty drive, but I want those to stay linked to the D: drive as the E: drive will adopt the same file structure. So, basically make the E: drive the D: drive (including copying all the files from the D: drive.) How would I acheive this?

Comment: Depending to what degree the `D:` drive is damaged, you could either simply copy and paste or pay for professional recovery services - two extremes but it completely depends on how faulty it is. Your question is too broad and is lacking this information for us to provide you with a detailed answer.

Comment: @adampski I can have access to the D: drive's contents. The essence of my question is not fixing a broken drive, but rather "swapping out" drives.

Comment: Copy and paste and change drive letter then within diskmgmt.msc

Comment: @adampski OK thanks, I was just worried something weird would happen with the enviornment variables or other information about file paths being messed up. If you write that in an answer I can accept!

Comment: @adampski Also, when reassigning, should I move the bad D: drive to another letter before I move the `E:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever software that uses the environment variables you're referring to, stop it or pause its function.

Simply copy and paste the data to your new drive. This can be achieved in File Explorer with simple copy and paste, or other GUI applications like FastCopy or command line options with Robocopy.

The benefit of using Robocopy or FastCopy is that you can resume if the copy process quits or bottles out mid way as these utilities can only copy the differences - this can be useful if it is a large transfer. Other benefits can also been speed as I've experienced Robocopy to be tremendously faster at copying lots of small files with the '/MT' option enabled set at a high value but this is dependent on disk i/o capabilities in your scenario.

So long as whatever software uses the environmental variables doesn't constantly tamper with the data while copying then it should be a painless experience, and wouldn't matter whether you change drive letter and copy or vice versa.